# how to use async function with custom hooks inside useEffects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want the get the moralis **useTokenPrice** to fetch an updated price after every five seconds, but from the rules of hook a react hook cannot be used inside useEffects.
how do i go about it.

my code

```
function SpeedPrice(props) {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState({
    symbol: "",
    token_address: "",
    price: "",
  });
  const MINUTE_MS = 5000;
  const address = props.address;
  const symbol = props.symbol;

  async function GetPrice() {
    const result = await useTokenPrice({ // moralis hook
      chain: "eth",
      address: address,
    });
    const usdPrice = result.data.formattedUsd;
    setPrice({ symbol: symbol, token_address: address, price: usdPrice });
  }

  // GetPrice(); infinite loop

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("call getprice"); 
      // GetPrice() error! React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function
    }, MINUTE_MS);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return price.price;
}
```

what i have done

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      // moved the function inside useEffects
      async function GetPrice() {
      const result = await useTokenPrice({ // moralis hook
        chain: "eth",
        address: address,
       });
      const usdPrice = result.data.formattedUsd;
      setPrice({ symbol: symbol, token_address: address, price: usdPrice });
      }
      GetPrice();
    }, MINUTE_MS);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
```

Comment: what is the return type of `useTokenPrice()` ?

Comment: I haven't used moralis, but looks like you can do `const {fetchTokenPrice, data}  = useTokenPrice( ...) ` then use `fetchTokenPrice()` wherever you want.

Comment: useTokenPrice returns a data Object,

Comment: All hooks (including useTokenPrice) should be defined unconditionally at the top level of the react component function (SpeedPrice).

Comment: Also, GetPrice should be wrapped in a useCallback and should be in the dependency list for useEffect

Answer (score 1):

[You can use hooks only in top level](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). But in your case
`useTokenPrice` return [`fetch`](https://github.com/MoralisWeb3/react-moralis/blob/dd7dd22d79a73159938c0625069ea39af711d5c2/src/hooks/web3ApiWrappers/useTokenPrice/useTokenPrice.ts#L53) function which you can use everywhere:

```
  const {fetchTokenPrice/**/, data /**/} = useTokenPrice({
    chain: 'eth',
    address: address
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(async () => {
      console.log('call getprice');
      await fetchTokenPrice(address); // 
    }, MINUTE_MS);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  const usdPrice = data.formattedUsd; // 
  return data.isLoading || data.isFetching ? 'Loading...' : usdPrice;
```

Comment: This solves it. Thanks @maksimr